# How to access the accelerometer of a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: c++, qt, windows-mobile, accelerometer

I've successfully ported my Qt-based C++ application to my girlfriend's Windows Mobile device. (A Samsung Omnia 2.)

However, it seems that the Qt Mobility Sensors API is not supported on Windows Mobile, so the application's specific features that would require the accelerometer are not working.

The question is, how to access the accelerometer of a Windows Mobile device from a C++ application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Omnia 2 has WM 6.5 Update you may use the unified sensor API [here](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2008/10/using-samsung-omnia-accelerometergsenso.html)

Comment: The link you gave me talks about doing this in managed code. I'd like to do it with native C++ code.

Comment: I guess I could just look at what native code the managed code uses underneath.